# Jest/React - How to use global object in unit tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I use CommonJS modules with require() except React, which is global:

```
// I don't want require React in every module:
// var React = require("react");

var MyComponent = React.createClass({ // React is global here
});
```

When running a unit test on MyComponent, Jest can't find React. Is there a way to tell Jest to insert a global React object? (I use npm and gulp-browserify.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Works for me with the following settings.

```
// package.json

"jest": {
  "scriptPreprocessor": "preprocessor.js",
  "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
    "react"
  ],
  "setupEnvScriptFile": "before_test.js"
}

// preprocessor.js

var ReactTools = require('react-tools');

module.exports = {
    process: function(src) {
        return ReactTools.transform(src);
    }
};

// before_test.js

React = require("react"); // Global React object
```

Comment: I found that I had to clear the haste cache to get this to work. `rm -rf node_modules/.haste_cache`

Comment: The setupEnvScriptFile configuration option has been deprecated for a while. Jest 15 removes it completely and replaces it with setupFiles. This option expects an array of file paths that are loaded in order before a test file is executed.
https://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/09/01/jest-15.html#setupenvscriptfile-vs-setupfiles