# How do I add React as a global whilst running unit tests?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, jestjs, react-rails

In my Rails project, I am using the react-rails gem, which does the following:

```
window.React = React;
```

This is pretty handy, but when I run unit tests using Jest, that global is not there and I get an error from the file containing the component I am testing saying that React is not defined.

If I define React in the component file using

```
import React from 'react';
```

Then it causes errors due to loading React twice.

How should I define a global `React` variable in my unit tests so they work?

Comment: maybe this is helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233357/jest-react-how-to-use-global-object-in-unit-tests

Comment: Thanks. Trying it, but not luck yet.

Comment: are you using webpack or babel? For you could set up a if/else branch to include the import line.  [See this example with babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-inline-environment-variables/)

Answer (score 0):

In your test file, do:

```
import React from 'react'

describe('something',() => {
  window.React = React
  // so when you require() your component, window.React is already set
  var MyComponent = require('MyComponent').default

  it('does something', () => {
    // do something
  })
})
```