# Handling global imports with Jest, React, and Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, webpack, jestjs

I recently started working on an already mature project where I am integrating the Jest testing framework. The project uses React with Webpack. In the webpack config, the team is using `webpack.ProvidePlugin` to provide React, lodash, and classnames (not what I would have done, but whatever).

The problem I'm running into, is that most of the React classes at the top of the file contain something like `React.Component`, which works fine because of the webpack base config. However, when I run the corresponding test file, I just get `React is not defined` unless I explicitly require React.

There is a `webpack.test.config` file that requires the base webpack config, but nevertheless I can't seem to get it so that I can run the tests without explicitly including `import React from 'react'` at the top of every file. I don't want to have to go manually import React in every file, anyone have any suggestions of what to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233357/jest-react-how-to-use-global-object-in-unit-tests

Comment: I ended up just removing the global imports and importing React in every file after discussing with the team. Neither of these solutions worked for me.

Comment: Yeah that's been my strategy as well. I prefer not to do globals. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is an anti-pattern to use globals in this case. I would just remove the globals and include `react` in every file

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jest's [`resolver`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#resolver-string) and when you get to the `react` import return the path to react. OR you could use jest's [`setupFile`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array) and `import React from 'react';` in there